# Solr stop words not seem to work , stop words are removed while indexing but still it at query time the stopwords are not removed in proximity search

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am using solr 8.2.0 . I am trying to configure proximity search in my solr but it doesnt seem to remove the stopwords in query .

```
    <fieldType name="psearch" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"  words="stopwords.txt" /> 
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.ClassicTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" /> 
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have mentioned the stopwords in stopwords.txt file in the directory , at the index time solr is removing the words as you can see in the picture :
[indexed terms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Udxg.png)

I also checked it in the analysis tab overthere the stopwords are being removed 
[Analysis tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwxTZ.png)

And here is the field :

```
<field name="pSearchField" type="psearch" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
    <copyField source="example" dest="pSearchField"/>
```

[Searching with proximity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFKJF.png)

And when I set the proximity to 1 or 2 or 3 it returns no result :
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE463.png)

Comment: Could you include the debug output that you get from Solr? Check the `debugQuery` box in the Solr UI when running your query. I would be interested in the values of `parsedquery` and `QParser`

Comment: @HectorCorrea 

This is what I get in debugQuery :
'
    "rawquerystring":"\"sent stuff\"~3",
    "querystring":"\"sent stuff\"~3",
    "parsedquery":"+DisjunctionMaxQuery((pSearchField:\"sent stuff\"~3))",
    "parsedquery_toString":"+(pSearchField:\"sent stuff\"~3)",
    "explain":{},
    "QParser":"ExtendedDismaxQParser",
'

Comment: You should add the interesting text from your images inline in the question if possible. In your analysis screen the screenshot cuts off before the interesting part (i.e. what's left after the stopwordfilter has run).

Comment: @MatsLindh Kindly check the image I have put on the complete image of analysis tab .

Comment: You should really use the indexed text and your query, and not just the stopwords. According to your example all tokens are being removed.

Comment: @MatsLindh https://ibb.co/nwSDsrm https://ibb.co/k3SFsk5 here have a look now . The only purpose behind setting up words is that when I make a proximity query something like "sent stuff"~3 it should not count the stopwords like in this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFKJF.png here it returns results when slop is 4 but it should return result on 1 as you can see in this entry "sent to prison for this stuff and that jail" here in between "sent" and "stuff" there is only one word to be counted that is "prison" and rest "to,for,this" are stopwords so those should be ignored .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with Solr 5 and up, since it no longer rewrites the position for each token when the stopfilter is invoked. This issue, with a few suggestions of how to fix it, is tracked in [SOLR-6468](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-6468).

The easiest solution is [to introduce a mapping char filter factory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/charfilterfactories.html#CharFilterFactories-solr.MappingCharFilterFactory), but I'm skeptical to it changing characters internally in a string. (i.e. `"to" => ""` also affecting `veto` and not just `to`). This can possible be handled with multiple [PatternReplaceCharFilterFactories](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/charfilterfactories.html#CharFilterFactories-solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory) instead.

Another option shown in the thread for the ticket is to use a custom filter that rewrites the position data for each token:

```
package filters;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenFilter;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionIncrementAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory;

public class RemoveTokenGapsFilterFactory extends TokenFilterFactory {

    public RemoveTokenGapsFilterFactory(Map<String, String> args) {
        super(args);
    }

    @Override
    public TokenStream create(TokenStream input) {
        RemoveTokenGapsFilter filter = new RemoveTokenGapsFilter(input);
        return filter;
    }

}

final class RemoveTokenGapsFilter extends TokenFilter {

    private final PositionIncrementAttribute posIncrAtt = addAttribute(PositionIncrementAttribute.class);

    public RemoveTokenGapsFilter(TokenStream input) {
        super(input);
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        while (input.incrementToken()) {
            posIncrAtt.setPositionIncrement(1);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

There currently is no perfect, built-in solution to this issue as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks mate . I added a custom filter like the code snippet you attached and its working perfectly fine . Keep up the good work .